# ComponentDidUpdate not calling for the same component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have a component and it has a state object like;

`this.state = {
   actionResponse: null,
 };`

and I check the value of actionResponse in

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if (this.props.detailState.actionResponse !== prevProps.detailState.actionResponse) {
        this.showToast(this.props.detailState.actionResponse,'bottom','OK', 'danger');
    }
}
```

For the first time I used the component, it calls the showToast method and go back. Second time it doesn't call the showToast because actionResponse is the same. Should I reset the value of actionResponse on goBack()? Or is there any other method to handle it?

Comment: What is the `actionResponse` and when do you want to show the toast?

Comment: actionsResponse is the response that received from the API after a post request. When it changes I would like to show toast with the data of actionResponse

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidUpdate` you should set `actionResponse` back to the default value, `null` in this case, after you perform your action (showing the toast).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if (this.props.detailState.actionResponse !== prevProps.detailState.actionResponse) {
        this.showToast(this.props.detailState.actionResponse,'bottom','OK', 'danger');
        this.props.resetActionResponse();
    }
}
```

`resetActionResponse` would look something like:

`resetActionResponse = () => this.setState({actionResponse: null})`

Comment: Actually, I tried it and didn't work. Then, I implemented the function to the action of the component and it worked.